# error using type converter for application setting

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, settings, type-conversion

After reading some of the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) I thought I had figured out how to use a custom type as an app setting via the visual studio designer.

The designer stores my string happily enough but I get an error message when I run a unit test to see if I can actually use the setting.

I was getting serialization errors on some of the other types that make up the custom type in question - I made them go away by reluctantly making several properties setters public. BUT the docs suggest that if a Type Converter is supplied that it will be used in lieu of serialization. Must I provide a type converter for every type that makes up the type I want as  a setting?

Cheers,
Berryl

## generated code from designer setting

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("8 hours")]
public global::Smack.Core.Lib.Domains.Temporal.TimeQuantity WorkQuota_Daily {
    get {
        return ((global::Smack.Core.Lib.Domains.Temporal.TimeQuantity)(this["WorkQuota_Daily"]));
        }
    }
```

## unit test and error

```
    [Test]
    public void WorkQuota_Daily_CanRead() {
        var setting = Properties.Settings.Default.WorkQuota_Daily;
        Assert.That(setting, Is.EqualTo(TimeQuantity.Hours(8)));
    }
Test failed: System.ArgumentException : The property 'WorkQuota_Daily' could not be created from it's default value. 
Error message: There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.Deserialize()
at System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.get_PropertyValue()
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
C:\Users\Lord & Master\Documents\Projects\Smack\trunk\src\ConstructionAdmin.TestingSupport\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs(211,0): at Smack.ConstructionAdmin.TestingSupport.Properties.Settings.get_WorkQuota_Daily()
General\ApplicationSettingsTests.cs(22,0): at Smack.ConstructionAdmin.TestingSupport.General.ApplicationSettingsTests.WorkQuota_Daily_CanRead()
```

## type converter

```
public class TimeQuantityTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            var v = ((string)value).Split();
            var amt = v[0];
            var unit = v[1];
            var timeSliceFactory = new TimeSliceFactory();
            var map = TimeSliceFactory.GetUnitMap(timeSliceFactory);
            var key = unit.ToLowerInvariant();
            if (!map.ContainsKey(key)) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("There is no time slice unit key fpr '{0}", key));
            return new TimeQuantity(amt, map[key]);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", ((TimeQuantity) value).Amount, ((TimeQuantity) value).Unit.PluralForm);
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

## settings file (several User settings ommited)

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
public sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("8 hours")]
    public global::Smack.Core.Lib.Domains.Temporal.TimeQuantity WorkQuota_Daily {
        get {
            return ((global::Smack.Core.Lib.Domains.Temporal.TimeQuantity)(this["WorkQuota_Daily"]));
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Monday")]
    public global::System.DayOfWeek StartDay {
        get {
            return ((global::System.DayOfWeek)(this["StartDay"]));
        }
    }
}
```

## Update (Fixed!)

Answer goes to the first person that sees what part of the puzzle I was missing. Hint #1 - the original TypeConverter code was fine. Hint # 2 - The System.ComponentModel is pretty powerful!

Comment: What does your settings file look like?

Comment: @Chris. I posted more of the generated code at the end of my post, as well as my latest change in the TypeConverter to use an InstanceDescriptor. The other settings in the settings file are usable.

Comment: @Chris. No, I don't want the InstanceDescriptor after all. Back to my original code and error. Grrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Berryl - I got this working (with some modifications, like creating my own TimeQuantity class). Did you remember to add a TypeConverterAttribute to your TimeQuantity class?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TimeQuantityTypeConverter))]
public class TimeQuantity
{
```

If you set a breakpoint inside your CanConvertFrom(...) and ConvertFrom(...) methods, you should see them hit when you read the property. Without that TypeConverter attribute, I get the same error you got.

Comment: Yes, holmes. The attribute was what I was missing. Cheers!